# 1980's Citadel miniature identification

Tags: content-identification, miniatures, wfrp-1e

In the mid-1980's, I had a Citadel Miniatures/Games Workshop miniature which looked exactly like Clint Eastwood's "Man with no name" character, but holding a hand crossbow rather than pistols. (Including cowboy style hat, poncho, and a cigar).

I'm sure he also had a picture and name in Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay 1st edition book (so would have been something in the Reikland/faux German style). I don't remember if the blister pack had that same name or a more generic label.

My goofle-fu is weak today, and I haven't been able to find anything resembling this figure. I'm hoping someone can help with identifying it.

Comment: Are you sure about the book? I think the 1e WFRP rule book had only drawings, no photographs of actual miniatures.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin I think he might be confusing it with Warhammer 1e.

Comment: I didn't have Warhammer 1e, just the WFRP book at the time. It was 30+ years ago, so my memory might be fuzzy :) , but pretty sure I had seen a painted picture of it 
 with a name somewhere (possibly a White Dwarf, or one of their adverts in hindsight).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably isn't the proper answer, but on page 23 of the Warhammer FRPG book there's an image of a "Bounty Hunter" that somewhat matches your query. Well, at least enough that I associate it somewhat with Clint Eastwood, with him as a search term in my head.

[image: Bounty Hunter]

His trappings include a "bow or crossbow", but no pistol, even if the picture seems to portray a pistol.

There's a [Ranger (C07) set](http://www.miniatures-workshop.com/lostminiswiki/index.php?title=C07_Rangers_%28Citadel%29), which includes a Bounty Hunter (not circled, second row, far right) that seems to match this:

[image]

Here's [the miniature in question (3C-04)](http://www.miniatures-workshop.com/lostminiswiki/index.php?title=Image:Citadel-C07-RA3C-04.jpg) on the wiki.

Comment: Thanks! It's definitely the Bounty Hunter model shown there (have now managed to find more images and they match), although I only had it as a single model rather than as a set.

Comment: @Brian I found a blogpost which seems to have drawn the same parallels to Clint Eastwood as you did: http://greblord-littlemen.blogspot.com/2014/10/citadel-25mm-c07-ranger-bounty-hunter.html

Comment: There is a comment at the end of that blog post "I always wanted this figure, since seeing it the original edition of The Warhammer RPG.", so maybe I'm not losing my nind after all...